# Conditional constraint formulation

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, logical-constraints

How can I create constraints to make sure $x=1$ if $k\geq 0$ and $x=0$ if $k<0$, where $x\in \{0,1\}$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$?

Here is my attempt:
\begin{equation}\label{cons:1}
    \begin{aligned}
        k\leq Mx
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Considering $M$ as the big-M, the above constraint makes sure $x=1$ if $k>0$. Surely, it is missing all other components.

Comment: Have you checked some of the questions posted on the site? Such as [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond) or [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari)?

Comment: maybe you edit your original question so that it contains this more concise statement. And as @EhsanK says, there may be an answer here already (namely, that strict inequalities require an epsilon to model).

Comment: @EhsanK, I have just checked those posts.

Comment: @MarcoLübbecke, do you mean I can introduce $k+\epsilon \leq Mx$ to make sure $x=1$ if $k\geq 0$ ? Then, what is the next constraint to ensure $x=0$ when $k<0$?

Comment: I feel the next constraint is $k\geq -M(1-x)$. Please correct me if I am wrong.