# How to formulate case distinctions in AMPLs objective function?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, linearization, ampl

This is my first real optimization problem I formulated and now trying to solve by using AMPL.

The following objective function is from a linear 0-1 LP means all variables $x_i^b\in\{0,1\}$, with $i\in[1,n]$ and $b$ referring to the type of the node, which means $0$ and $1$ say a node is or is not of a certain type.

The objective function is as follows with $A$ a set of nodes, $N[a]$ a set of all neighbours of $a$ including $a$, and $n$ a given number of types:

$$\min - \sum_{a\in A}f\left(\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf\left(\sum\limits_{b\in N[a]}x_i^b\right)\right)$$

with

$$
f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\{0,1\}\\
f(x):=\begin{cases}0,&x<1\\1,&x\geq 1\end{cases}
$$

I already heard that AMPL doesn't support the definition of functions/methods and that I have to use the [Big M method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) to create this objective function. I couldn't really figure out yet how to use the method to replace my case distinctions.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! Have you checked other questions on the site, such as this one: [In an integer program, how can I “activate” a constraint only if a decision variable has a certain value?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I suppose you mean $\min \sum\limits_{a\in A}f\left(\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^nf\left(\sum\limits_{b\in N[a]}x_i^b\right)\right)$ as the minus sign would indicate $\max$.

Comment: Note that if M is set too large, you can run into numeric problems - see e.g. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/3O7DsZuXIi4 so be careful to check that your solution really does satisfy the constraints.

Comment: yeah it has been a max but I thought to remember, that I have to minimise the objective function when all constraints are $\geq C$ maybe I was wrong (therefore I turned the max + to min -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\rho$ be some small value.
\begin{align}M \times f(x) &\geq x - 1 + \rho\\M \times (1 - f(x)) &\geq 1 - x - \rho\end{align}

Here is the small working code in Python `pulp`

```
import pulp as pl

prob = pl.LpProblem("Problem", pl.LpMinimize)
x = 1
f = pl.LpVariable("f_{0}", 0, 1, pl.LpBinary)
prob += f
M = 100
prob += M * f >= x - 1 + 0.001
prob += M * (1 - f) >= 1 - x - 0.0001

print(prob)
prob.solve()

for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: Can I ask for another detail - I am very interested in the "WHY" so why is it not possible to solve objective functions with case distinctions directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can express this objective using AMPL's builtin if-then-else expression. I think the following corresponds to what you want to write:

```
param n;

set A;
set N {A} within A;

var x {1..n, A};

maximize ObjFunc:
   sum {a in A} (
      if (1/n) * sum {i in 1..n} (
         if sum {b in N[a]} x[i,b] >= 1 then 1 else 0 )
      >= 1 then 1 else 0 );
```

General support for if-then-else is present in current AMPL MIP solver distributions (except that for CPLEX this feature is still in beta and it's necessary to use `cplexmp` rather than `cplex` to get it).