# Linearizing constraint with continuous and boolean variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization

I have two continuous variables $A$, $B$ and two binary variables $x$, $y$.

Condition: if $A = B \wedge x = 1 \wedge y=1$ then $z = 1$ else $z = 0$ from

- [In an integer program, how I can force a binary variable to equal 1 if some condition holds?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond)
- [In an integer program, how can I “activate” a constraint only if a decision variable has a certain value?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My current attempt is:

\begin{align}
A-B + \delta+x+y &\leq 2 + M \cdot k_1\\
B - A - \delta-x-y &\leq - 2 + M \cdot(1 - k_1)\\
B-A + \delta+x+y &\leq 2 + M \cdot k_2\\
A - B - \delta-x-y &\leq -2 + M \cdot(1 - k_2)\\
k_1 + k_2 - 1 &\leq z
\\k_1 &\geq z
\\k_2 &\geq z
\end{align}

where $k_1, k_2$ are boolean variables, but I am not getting the expected result.

Comment: I haven't checked your formulation, but what value of M did you use, and how did you choose that value?

Comment: I am choosing $ M = 1000$ which is higher than the upper bound of the problem

Comment: Perhaps you should spell out exactly in what way(s) the result is different than you expected.

Comment: Is $\delta$ a constant or variable? Is it nonnegative, strictly positive or what?

Comment: constant, $\delta = 0.000001$ small value

Comment: I cannot make any sense of your constraints. Consider, for example, the case where $z=1$. The second to last constraint is automatically true; the last forces $k_1=k_2=1$, which makes constraints 1 and three nonbinding. Now set $A=B$ and $x=y=0$. That satisfies constraints 2 and 4, but according to your problem statement, it should not be a feasible solution.

Comment: The last two constraints are intended to enforce $z=1\implies (k_1=1 \land k_2=1)$, but it is better to instead have $z\le k_1$ and $z\le k_2$, with no big-M.

Comment: ok, I have updated them in the question.

Comment: Is it fine now..?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors, so maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to model
$$z=1 \iff (A=B\land x=1 \land y=1).$$

To enforce $z=1 \implies (A=B\land x=1 \land y=1)$:
\begin{align}
-M(1-z) \le A - B &\le M(1-z)\\
z &\le x\\
z &\le y
\end{align}

To enforce the converse $(A=B\land x=1 \land y=1) \implies z=1$,
equivalently, $A>B\lor A<B\lor x=0 \lor y=0 \lor z=1$:
\begin{align}
B-A+\delta &\le M_1 (1-w_1)\\
A-B+\delta &\le M_2 (1-w_2)\\
w_1+w_2+(1-x)+(1-y) + z&\ge 1\\
w_1,w_2&\in\{0,1\}
\end{align}