# Mocking up conditional statements in LP

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, integer-programming, linearization, big-m, indicator-constraints

I would like to know how if condition statements in linear programming can be reformulated using indicator constraints, and hence solved as a mixed integer linear program. Specifically:

**1. Is it possible to formulate the problem below using indicators constraints, without using big-M? If so, how? I know that some solvers do it automatically but I am interested in doing it manually**
 **2. How to formulate it using big-M?**

Assume that the problem is given by:
[image]

For a more detailed example, assume that you have certain obligation at times 1, 2 and 3. You have 10 assets. First you want to see if you can meet the obligations by the first 5 assets before considering the remaining 5. The objective is to find the minimum amount of asset that you can invest in to meet the obligations.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked some of the questions posted on the site? There are several questions that have answers to these types of constraints such as [In an integer program, how I can force a binary variable to equal 1 if some condition holds?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond) or [In an integer program, how can I “activate” a constraint only if a decision variable has a certain value?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari)?

Comment: I have just read these questions, but I do not think they answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to enforce the following logical proposition:
$$\bigvee_{i=6}^{10} (x_i>0) \implies \bigwedge_{j=1}^{5} (x_j=1)$$

You can model this by introducing a binary variable $y$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_i &\le y&&\text{for $i\in\{6,\dots,10\}$}\\
y&\le x_j &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,5\}$}\\
\end{align}

Comment: I have added a more explanation in my answer and attempted to apply your solution to it.

Comment: My answer applies to case 1.

Comment: Thank you. I suspect case 2 can only be dealt with big-M formulation and only if xi>0 for i=1,..5 though I am not sure.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the first part is yes, provided that you are using a solver that supports indicator constraints. As far as I know, there is no "standard" notation for it. Something like $$a_1 x_1 \le b \implies x_2 = 0$$would seem reasonable to me. The "else" part is tricky, since it deals with the case $a_1 x_1 > b$ and strict inequalities are a no-no. You could approximate it by $$a_1 x_1 \ge b + \epsilon \implies x_1 = (1,\dots,1)^\prime$$where $\epsilon > 0$ is some small tolerance value. Note that this would make any solution with $b < a_1 x_1 < b + \epsilon$ infeasible.

A big-M formulation for the simplified version might look like the following, where $y\in\lbrace 0, 1\rbrace$ is a new binary variable, $M_1$ is a valid upper bound on $a_1x_1$ and $M_2$ is a valid upper bound on $b+\epsilon - a_1x_1$:
\begin{equation*}
a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 \le b \\
a_1 x_1 \le b + M_1y \\
a_1 x_1 \ge b + \epsilon - M_2(1-y) \\
x_2 \le y \\
x_1 \ge y \\
0 \le x_1, x_2 \le 1.
\end{equation*}
There is one important catch here. This only works if $a_1 \ge b+\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have provided a more detailed example in the question. Does your solution still hold?

Comment: Not for case 2. I'm not sure if it can be fixed for case 1, but it's probably not worth it. There could be a problem if the second tier variables are much cheaper than the first tier variables. It's much easier (and arguably safer) to solve a restricted LP (second tier variables locked at zero) and then solve the full problem only if the restricted problem is infeasible.