# How to transform these conditional constraints to linear integer ones in a more efficient way?

Tags: optimization, big-m, indicator-constraints, convex-hull

The conditional constraints A and B can be transformed to a set of linear integer constraints as follows:

A) $\text{if} \ x_1=0 \ \text{then} \ d_1=1 \ \text{else} \ d_1= 0\\ x_1\in {\rm I\!R}^{\geq 0} , d_1 \in \{0,1\}, M=10^6, m=10^{-6}$

transformed to

$\qquad \text{A1)} \quad m(1-d_1) \leq x_1 \leq M(1-d_1)$

B) $\text{if} \ x_2 < K \ \text{then} \ y= x_2 \ \text{else} \ y \leq K;\\ x_2,y \in {\rm I\!R}^{\geq 0}, d_2 \in \{0,1\}, \\ K \text{ is positive constant}$

transformed to

$\qquad \text{B1)}\ y \leq K $

$\qquad \text{B2)}\ {-M} \cdot (1-d_2) \leq x_2 - K \leq M \cdot d_2$

$\qquad \text{B3)}\ {-M} \cdot d_2 \leq x_2 - y \leq M \cdot d_2 $

---

Q1) Is the above transformation correct?

Q2) How can I formulate A and B in a more efficient way (such as convex-hull) rather than the big-M method ?

Comment: what are you decisions variables? are they binary?

Comment: In the first set of constraints (A and A1): x1 is a non-negative continuous decision variable and d1 is a binary indicator decision variable. In the second set of constraints (B,B1,B2 and B3), x2 and y are non-negative continuous decision variables , d2 is a binary indicator decision variable and K is a positive constant. M / m are relatively  large / small constants of the Big-M approach. @Betty

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can improve on A1 (which looks correct), other than perhaps tightening the bounds $M$ and $m$ (which would be dependent on the specifics of the problem). Regarding B, would the solver prefer larger values of $y$ over smaller values? (Again, this is problem dependent.) If so, you could eliminate the use of a binary variable and just use the constraints \begin{equation*}y\le x_2\\y \le K\end{equation*}(in which I'm assuming that your $k$ and $K$ are the same thing). If not, I think you need a big-M formulation, and yours looks correct.

Comment: Yes, K and k are the same. However, the constraint you have proposed is non-linear and I am seeking for a linear transformation. On the other hand, I am looking for a more efficient method such as convex-hull as suggested here : https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari/163?r=SearchResults&s=6|19.8167#163 @prubin

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean when you say I proposed a nonlinear constraint.

Comment: Doesn't x2.y term in the constraint impose non-linearity to the problem?! @prubin

Comment: I don't see any multiplication of $y$ and $x_2$. You're not referring to $y\le x_2$, are you??

Comment: Sorry, there was a problem with my browser. Now I see them clearly with another browser. Thanks @prubin