# Conditional Constraint in MIP

Tags: binary-variable, logical-constraints

I need to formulate a conditional constraint for a binary variable z defined as:

$z_{i,j,k}$, $\ \ i=1:10 \ , \ j=1:5 \ , \ k=1:3$

If any $z_{i,j,3} = 1$ then  $z_{i,j,1} + z_{i,j,2} = 0 \ \  \forall i,j$

Answer (score 6):

How about $z_{i,j,1} + z_{i,j,2} \leq 2 \cdot (1 - z_{i,j,3}) \quad \forall i,j$ ?

For more context, I refer you to [this excellent self-answer by user D.W. on CS.SX](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12118/64655), which includes a link to a helpful [gallery of such common "building blocks"](http://faculty.nps.edu/dell/docs/Formulettes060425.pdf), all with practical examples stated in prose.

Comment: Oooh -- that is a great answer on CS.SX. On OR.SE, there's [this one](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/33/in-an-integer-program-how-i-can-force-a-binary-variable-to-equal-1-if-some-cond) and [this one](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/76/in-an-integer-program-how-can-i-activate-a-constraint-only-if-a-decision-vari) but the CS one is quite comprehensive.

Comment: For a tighter formulation, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3651532/converting-a-conditional-constraint-if-then-to-integer-linear-programming/3652075#3652075).

Comment: @RobPratt mind to add the tighter formulation as its own answer? As a OR user, I am usually satisfied once my formulation cuts away all undesired integer/binary solutions (and the solver converges quickly enough).

Answer (score 6):

For simplicity, I will omit the $i$ and $j$ subscripts.
Rewriting your logical proposition in conjunctive normal form somewhat automatically yields two linear constraints:
\begin{equation}
z_3 \implies (\neg z_1 \land \neg z_2) \\
\neg z_3 \lor (\neg z_1 \land \neg z_2) \\
(\neg z_3 \lor \neg z_1) \land (\neg z_3 \lor \neg z_2) \\
((1- z_3) + (1- z_1) \ge 1) \land ((1- z_3) + (1- z_2) \ge 1) \\
(z_3 + z_1 \le 1) \land (z_3 + z_2 \le 1)
\end{equation}
Note that the big-M constraint $$z_1 + z_2 \le 2(1-z_3)$$ is weaker, being an aggregation of the previous two constraints.  For example, the big-M constraint does not cut off $z=(3/4,1/4,1/2)$.