# How to model this chain of logical implication

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, binary-variable, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

I would like to seek some advice on modeling the following (chain of) logical implication:

For instance $\omega_{xy}$ might indicate precedence, i.e., $x$, $y$ being the nodes $x$ and $y$, respectively. Thus if $\omega_{xy}$$=1$, it implies that the departure time of the vehicle from node $x $ is to be less than or equal to the arrival time at node $y$.

Say for instance, there is an additional node $z$, which also to be visited as is always behind temporally, and for other nodes that are also temporally behind $z$, such as $z_1...z_n$

Hence, I would like to force the logical implication such that

$\omega_{xy}$$=1$ $\implies$ $\omega_{xz}$$=1$

$\omega_{xy}$$=1$ $\implies$ $\omega_{xz_1}$$=1$

...

$\omega_{xy}$$=1$ $\implies$ $\omega_{xz_n}$$=1$

Appreciate your kind guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: Which are variables and which are constants? What types are the variables?

Comment: What's the difference between the first two implications (assuming $x$ and $y$ are both variables)?

Comment: In any case, see whether this answers your question: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/76/38

Comment: Hi, I have just edited my question. Sorry for the prior unclear description. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enforce $x = 1 \implies y = 1$ for binary variables $x$ and $y$, impose linear constraint $x \le y$.  You can derive this constraint via conjunctive normal form:
$$
x \implies y \\
\lnot x \lor y \\
(1 - x) + y \ge 1 \\
x \le y
$$

Comment: Thanks! Guess I overcomplicated stuff myself.