# Linearization of the shifted copy of a function

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization

Suppose in a model I have the expression $y_{1}(x) = 10 + 5 x^2$ where $x \in [0,20]$ is a continuous variable. In order to be able to use an MILP solver, I piecewise linearise $z_{1} = x^2$, by choosing $\{0,5,10,20\}$ as arbitrary values for $x$, as follows:

$
x = 0 \lambda_{1} + 5 \lambda_{2}  + 10 \lambda_{3}  +  20 \lambda_{4}  \\
z_{1} =0 \lambda_{1} + 25 \lambda_{2}  + 100 \lambda_{3}  +  400 \lambda_{4}  \\
\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}  + \lambda_{3}  + \lambda_{4} = 1 
$

In the same model, I have to deal with the function:

$y_{2}(x,d) = 20 + 5 (x-d)^2, d \ge 0$, $d$ is a variable

Is there a way to express $(x-d)^2$ in a linearised form in terms of $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}, \lambda_{3}, \lambda_{4}$?

Please consider that $y_{1}(x)$ could be any nonlinear function, the quadratic form stated here is just an example.

Comment: Is $d$ really a variable of the whole model, and not a parameter? (Asking as the function is $y_2(x)$ and not $y_2(x, d)$)

Comment: d is a decision variable. $y_{2}(x)$ should be written $y_{2}(x,d)$, you are right.

Comment: First, is $x$ constrained to $\lbrace 0, 5, 10, 20\rbrace$ in the model? (Your constraints imply this.) Next, is $d$ discrete, and if so can you enumerate the possible values of $d$.

Comment: The three equations $x= ...$ , $z_{1} = ...$ , $\lambda_{1} + ...$ are supposed to piecewise linear approximate $x^2$ within [0,20]. The points $x=0$, $x=5$, $x=10$, $x=20$ are chosen arbitrarily for this example.   $d$ is not discrete. The only constraint imposed on $d$ is $x-d \ge 0.0$.

Comment: $(x-d)^2=x^2 - 2xd + d^2$ and then you can look at https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-continuous-variables?rq=1 for the middle term.

Comment: Well, I hoped to be able to avoid repeatedly applying piecewise linearization because the model then becomes huge. Do you think I could succeed by using using a Global Optimization Solver such as BARON?