# Mixed Integer Programming with product of a binary variable and multiple continuous variables

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, linearization

Suppose we have a binary variable $x$ and two non-negative continuous variables $y_1\ge 0$ and $y_2 \ge 0$. How can we linearize $xy_1 y_2$ ?

FYI, this is a follow up question to this:
[How to linearize the product of a binary and a non-negative continuous variable?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/39/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-a-binary-and-a-non-negative-continuous-variable)

Comment: You cannot. Just consider the case when you don't have $x$, there is no magic way to linear a bilinear product of two continuous variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Johan Löfberg said, it cannot be done directly. You can get an approximate solution in two steps.

1. First, approximate the product of $y_1$ and $y_2$ using a new variable $z.$ See, for instance, [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-continuous-variables), and specifically the answers involving McCormick envelopes.
2. Now linearize the product of $x$ and $z$ using the link in your question.

Answer (score 6):

I would start with a non-convex solver like Gurobi. Gurobi can only do quadratic terms, but that is not a real limitation:

```
 z1 = x*y1
 z2 = z1*y2
```