# OR constraint in Gurobi - Python

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, python, gurobi, constraint

I'm new to Gurobi in Python and I am wondering if there is way to code the following constraints:

**1-** $\sum x_i =0$ for all $i\in A$ OR   for all $i \in B$
where A and B are distinch sets of integers and $x_i$ are binary variables.

**2-**  $\sum_{i=0}^{10} x_i =0$ OR $\sum_{i=0}^{10}  x_i =1$

Question:
Is there a way to express the "Or" in one of the above constraints ?/code in Gurobi (maybe something like addConstrOr instead of addConstr)

My thoughts: maybe something like that would work for (1) and (2), but I am not sure if it is possible

- `model. addConstr (sum( x [ i] for i in A) ==0) or model. addConstr (sum( x [ i] for i in B) ) ==0)`
- `model. addConstr (sum( x [ i] for i in range(0,10) ) ==0) or model. addConstr (sum( x [ i] for i in range(0,10) ) ==1)`

Comment: It is not Gurobi specific, but by introducing binary variables capturing the logic, you can easily model it directly. For point two, introduce a binary variable $y$ and have $\sum_{i=0}^{10}x_i=y$. Now $y$ controls whether the sum is zero or one, and it cannot be anything else.

Comment: @Sune Thank you! I'm wondering if there is a way to express this in Gurobi, maybe the equivalent in Cplex would be something like model. add ( (sum....)+(sum....)>=1) -as at least one of the both sums should hold-, but not sure of gurobi –

Comment: [Single reference for Mixed Integer Programming formulations to linearize, handle logical constraints and disjunctive constraints, do Big M, etc?](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/57/491)...particularly this [quick reference document](https://www.msi-jp.com/xpress/learning/square/10-mipformref.pdf)

Comment: @M.Badaoui well yes, in gurobi's python API this would be something like `model.addConstr( sum( x[i] for i in range(0,11)) == y) ` where $y$ is declared as a binary decision variable